# get the second element from a list of elements with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get the inner html of an element (with get_attribute('innerHTML')) but it doesnt have and id or class and there are multiple elements with the same tag name

> test1=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

This gets the whole list of elements with the same tag name but this doesnt work because get_attribute doesnt work with multiple elements

> test2=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("td")

this works but gets the very first td elements but i want the second td element

How do i do this correctly?

Comment: I ended up being alot easier than i thought if anybody has the same problem use this >name=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[1].get_attribute('innerHTML')

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath like below to get the second td of every row in a table.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tr/td[2]")
```

modify xpath to go to your required table if you need it from a particular table.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question the following line of code is returning you the very first td element :

```
test2=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("td")
```

To retrieve the text within the second td element you can use either of the following lines of code :

- **`xpath`** :

  ```
  test2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//tr//following::td[2]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- **`css_selector`** :

  ```
  test2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//table > tr > td:nth-last-child(2)").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```

> **Note** : The last part of the **`xpath`** and the **`css_selector`** will definitely identify the second `<td>` element but you may have to require to adjust the initial part as per your `HTML DOM`